# MYSQL before insert trigger not firing

Tags: mysql, triggers

For some reason my database in MYSQL Workbench is allowing me to insert out-of-range data into the 'occupancy column', which it should not.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cecsproject`.`room` (
  `type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `occupancy` INT NOT NULL,
  `number-beds` INT NULL,
  `type-beds` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `price` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`type`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER occupancy_check 
    BEFORE INSERT ON room
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF (new.occupancy > 5) 
        THEN SET new.occupancy = NULL;
    ELSEIF (new.occupancy < 1)
        THEN SET new.occupancy = NULL;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here's the query I run:

```
INSERT INTO room
VALUES ('regular', 0, 2, 'full', 100);

select * from room;
```

And here is the result:

```
regular 0   2   full    100
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Column `occupancy` is  `INT NOT NULL`. So why do you try to `SET new.occupancy = NULL`?

Comment: So it will reject the insertion.

Comment: You are right - and it "works" on [sqlfiddel here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5438/1). But I would just ["throw" an error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html).